# Need PHP recipe for Google Oauth2 signon

Tags: php, google-oauth

I currently have a web site (shared server) written in raw PHP (no framework) that I have a Google button that allows users to click, to log on to my web site.  The code (from Google) sends the user over to Google, then sends them back to my web site along with their verified email address.  At that point, I handle logging them in to my web site.
A few weeks ago, Google wrote to say that Google Identity Toolkit is going away, and will stop on November 30.  They recommended migrating to Firebase Authentication or Identity Platform for Google Cloud.  I understand that Firebase is for Apps, and Identity Platform for Google Cloud has no PHP solution.
I am now looking at Google Auth Library for PHP:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php
However, I can't find any examples or documentation on how to use it.  I am expecting that I will need a bit of code for my login page, and some code for that page that receives the info sent by Google.
Where do I even get started, to get code/logic for a simple Google login?
  FYI: I've run my web site for about 15 years, and I haven't really kept up with web technology.  I write in PHP and some Javascript, plus a little JQuery.
Here is the recipe that I used many years ago to get my current login setup working: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-google-account-oauth_231.html (It now has broken links to some important images.)

Comment: Which permissions (from Google) do you think you need?

Comment: All I need is to get an email address.  (Also, I didn't mention it above, but I already have a Google Cloud Platform account, I set up a project, and I have a client ID and client secret.)

Comment: I've migrated the OAuth2 *starter demo* to a project I was working on. You essentially create a project under Google developer console and select which APIs you need then download the credentials to use in your project. The authorization of the *Consent Screen* was a breeze, took me about 5 days.

Comment: Where is the "OAuth2 starter demo"?

Comment: Its called QuickStart. Here's it for Gmail auth when using PHP: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php